# TCP send message to localhost on port - node.js

Tags: node.js, tcp, server-side

I am trying to create using **nodes core only** a message sent by one server to another server (not clients just server-to-server).

In fact the servers are both the same server message is sent between 2 apps that must not be linked together. one must receive a remote message from the other.

I am looking over all google things and node docs but can't make sense of a few parts of the code for sending.

**The first server only should receive messages:**

```
var net=require('net');

var server1=net.createServer(function(nets){
    nets.addListener('message',function(data){
        console.dir(data);
        });
    });
server1.listen(8000,'localhost');
```

**The second server should only send messages:**

```
var net=require('net');

var server2=net.createConnection(8000,'localhost',function(nets){
    nets.on('connect',function(){
        nets.write('message',{'a':1,'foo':'bar'});
        });
});
```

I am having trouble understanding the docs though, I defiantly need to use net because the 2 apps must not be attached to each other so eventEmitter is a no-no

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The node.js documentation has some easy examples of both a [TCP server](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/net.html#net_net_createserver_options_connectionlistener) as well as a [TCP client](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/net.html#net_net_connect_options_connectionlistener) that you can tweak for your application-specific logic.

Also: the documentation for [Socket](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/net.html#net_class_net_socket) shows what you can do with an incoming or outgoing socket connection. As you will see, you cannot write JSON directly with node core. You have to stringify it first: `sock.write(JSON.stringify({ foo: 'bar' }));`